# Wicket RadioChoice default selected

Tags: radio-button, wicket

I have a RadioChoice component with an attached model. The radio choice is associated with a boolean field, hence I have to radio buttons (yes/no). My problem is that the no-button gets pre-selected when the page renders, because the boolean field is set to false. Is there a way to prevent this from happening, as I don't want to have a pre-selected value.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: is your backing Model a boolean or a Boolean? I would try using a Boolean with a null value on page render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an HTML point of view, it's not recommended to omit the pre-selected radio value (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#radio). It's also rather irritating for the user, since there's no way to unselect all values within a radio group if he/she accidentally clicks one. You should probably rethink your UI - is there room for a third 'Unknown' option?

Comment: It's mandatory to check one of the options. However, we want to ensure that the user has actually chosen a value and not just forgotten to change the pre-defined value.

Comment: Can you use a Boolean (big-B) and leave it null, then? Or add the 'Unknown' option, selected by default, but hide it from the user, then validate on submission that a selection has been made.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `RadioChoice` component is attached with a model; when you write 
`yourRadioChoice.getValue()` you always get your model value not updated value. For prevent this you can use a temporary variable.

```
yourRadioChoice.add(new AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior () {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1662824638126944259L;          

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {  
                   // you can get current value here and set to your temporary variable
                   // then use anywhere
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use Booleans, but rather primitives then you can override isSelected in RadioChoice:

```
@Override
protected boolean isSelected(Boolean object, int index, String selected) {
    return false;
}
```